# Remove toolbar from specific category products added as a block in cms page?

Tags: layout, xml, phtml, category-products, toolbar

I added below line in CMS Home Page to display products of a certain category in Magento 1.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="179" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Now I can see the products of that category. But I also got a tool-bar as a phtml file (I got this using *Template Path Hints*). Now I would like to know how can I find which XML file include this phtml file ? I would like to remove that inclusion of phtml file from XML file.

Comment: A quick tip: If you search for the template path and name you should find the XML file(s) that render this block. You can then manipulate it in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your theme and locate app/design/frontend/ [ your interface name] / [your theme name] /template/catalog/product/list.phtml
2. Take a copy of this and rename `list.phtml` to `homepage-list.phtml`.
3. Remove this code `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>` from around line 39 and 131 and save.
4. Update your CMS home page to this `{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="179" template="catalog/product/homepage-list.phtml"}}`
5. Refresh your page.

Comment: Thanks @krishna ijjada for your reply. Yes, you are right. But my intension is little different. How did this toolbar display here ? I think this toolbar is included through a XML file, because when I on the Template Path Hint I got a hint of .phtml file. (Am I right or wrong).  I would like to remove that inclusion from that XML file. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you are right, toolbar is adding from catalog.xml, you can remove it by removing toolbar.phtml in the catalog.xml but it will effect product catalog.

Comment: Thanks @krishna ijjada for your wise reply. I removed *toolbar.phtml* from **catalog.xml** of current theme and base theme. I also removed *toolbar.phtml* from **catalogsearch.xml** of current theme and base theme. But it is still displaying. 




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu2UJ.png

Comment: Ok, find/search toolbar.phtml in catalog.xml. you can find it in multiple places, comment the code and remove   the cache, check one more time. Still facing , I am available on stack chatroom.

Comment: I searched *toolbar.phtml* in **catalog.xml** and  **catalogsearch.xml**   and removed *toolbar.phtml* from multiple places of those files before your comment. Cache is disabled. But the toolbar is still displaying. The site is using **theme254k**. This Theme is behaving uneven behavior from beginning. What to do? Thanks.